# Creating a rectangular Heatmap from two columns of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Pandas dataframe like this -

[image]

The value in column 's' is the accuracy of a model for the corresponding values of 'k' and 'w'. So, it's strictly between 0 and 1.

I want to plot a heatmap such that a 7x2 grid of k (7 values) along X axis and w (2 values) along y axis will be created and the corresponding cell will be colored depending on the value of s.

I tried Seaborn's headmap function but it doesn't let me define which column to use to color the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

flights = df.pivot("w", "k", "s")
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True,  linewidths=.5, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]